# Active Admin Comments: "Comment wasn't saved, text was empty"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, activeadmin, uuid

I've got a brand new rails app (7.1.0) (with a few models) that I have set up with ActiveAdmin and the only model that works is my Admin model. I noticed that the admin model is the only table that has sequential ID's and the rest use UUIDS:

```
create_table "admins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admins_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admins_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "bids", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "state", default: "bid"
    t.uuid "vendor_id", null: false
    t.uuid "job_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["job_id"], name: "index_bids_on_job_id"
    t.index ["vendor_id"], name: "index_bids_on_vendor_id"
  end
```

This is my only hint. When I post a comment, I see that it *is* including the comment body, but seems to *ROLLBACK* when it checks for the bid model (above) but always looks for `id = nil` rather than the id (which is in post body as the resource id, as expected).

Why would it fail to correctly query the resource (in this case, the bid) when I make the comment? What should I do to correct this issue?